# Difference between creating contract with and without using new

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

Hi can anyone tell me the differnece between creating contract using a new operator and creating contract by passing the address.

Example:

```
contract A{
    uint256 public num = 10;
    function get() returns(uint){
        return num;
    }
}

contract B{
    function get() returns(uint){
        A a = new A();
        a.get();
    }
}
```

and

```
contract B{
    function get(address add) returns(uint){
        A a = A(add);
        a.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy a contract with **new address** that was not exist in network before then we can use

> A a = new A();

It generate address `a` of the `contract A` . Here a holds the address of contract which was just deployed.

If you have address of contract which was already deployed in the network and you want to use in current contract then you have to convert that `address to contract type`. After this It will be recognized as this particular address is of contract address type.

> A a = A(address_of_contract_A);

This will avoid the confusion of either address is `EOA`(externally owned account) or `CA`(contract account).

Answer (score 0):

In the first scenario, each time you call `B.get()`, you will deploy a new instance of A. If you call it 10 times, there will be 1 B contract, and 10 A contracts.

In the second scenario, contract A is already deployed somewhere, and you simply pass its address to the get call. In this scenario, a single instance of A can be used multiple times.